# Spring Boot Checkbox Array not working as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, spring-boot, checkbox

I have an array of checkboxes all with the same names which I submit to a Spring Boot Controller. I build a Bootstrap DataTable using Jquery/Ajax using data which receive from the database and test if I should select the checkbox when the page loads. I do this by using this code:

```
if (data['isChecked'] == "1") {
   return "<input type='checkbox' name='fieldIdList' value='1_' checked>";
} else {
   return "<input type='checkbox' name='fieldIdList' value='1_'>";
}
```

This code loops, so the next checkbox value will be 2_ and the next 3_, etc, etc.

When the page loads the table displays 10 rows and my first 2 checkboxes are shown as selected. This is correct.

Now when I submit this form without changing the state of any of the checkboxes to my Controller code below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/dataTable", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postDataTable(@RequestParam("fieldIdList") List<String> fieldIdList){
    return "";
}
```

I get 2 entries in my fieldIdList:

"1_"

"2_"

This is correct because only my first 2 checkboxes was checked. But when I uncheck any of the checkboxes and submit again, I get a funny result. In the example below, I unchecked the 2nd checkbox and then submitted the form again, my entries in my fieldIdList:

"1_"

"1_"

"1_"

"2_"

By unchecking the second checkbox and submitting, I suspected to get only 1 entry in my fieldIdList as "1_"

Also after I submit, the page is redirected the the previous page, so when I enter this page again, all the Lists are loaded as new, so there can be no previous values still stored in them.

Not sure if this is a Jquery/Ajax issue or Java issue or just a problem with the object between the chair and laptop :)

Because the DataTable is paging, I had to add this piece of code below in order to get all the rows of the DataTable. Not sure if this is causing the issue.

```
    // Handle form submission event
    $('#manageFormFields').on('submit', function (e) {
        var dataTable = $('#formFieldsDataTable').DataTable();
        var form = this;

        // Iterate over all checkboxes in the table
        var tableData = dataTable.$('input, select').serializeArray();
        $(form).append(tableData);
        $.each(tableData, function () {
            // If element doesn't exist in DOM
            if (!$.contains(document, form[this.name])) {
                // Create a hidden element
                $(form).append(
                    $('<input>')
                        .attr('type', 'hidden')
                        .attr('name', this.name)
                        .val(this.value)
                );
            }
        });
    });
```

The generated HTML:

[image]

Thank you for your time.

Comment: How do you build the data that you submit to the RestController?

Comment: Af the page loads and the DataTable is complete, It's a pure HTML form which is being submitted to the URL as specified value = "/admin/dataTable". There is however a piece of code I had to put in place to handle the submit. Because the DataTable is pageable, I had to add this piece of code to get all rows before the submit. I added it to the question now.

Comment: And have you debugged your code? And had a look at the generated HTML page?

Comment: Yes and I added the generated HTML to the question now

Comment: The problem seems to be coming from the ```$('#manageFormFields').on('submit', function (e) {``` piece of code. If I add ```if(this.name != "fieldIdList")``` just before ```if (!$.contains(document, form[this.name])) {``` then it works 100%. Not sure if this is correct so I will go with it for now but leave the questions open for someone to help me on fixing that. The tableData is appended to the form so it should be in the DOM and not go into the ```if (!$.contains(document, form[this.name])) {``` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am truly sorry for wasting your time.
It turns out I was adding the list of rows twice to the Datatable. Thus there were 2 fields with the same name and value. When I uncheck the one, the other one is still present and that is why the controller still picked it up.

I could not see this in the HTML output because the source only shows what is visible on screen(the first 10 rows).

So when I paged through all the rows I noticed another checkbox was checked and then saw that I added the rows twice.

Removing the duplicates fixed my problem.

Thank you!!